# How to stop receiving mails from a specific account?

Tags: icloud, mail.app, email

Macbook Pro has made my life very miserable, in a struggle to make something out of it, I'm trying to atleast stop receiving mails from my gmail account with out disabling it. My gmail account is being spammed heavily even after setting so many filters. So i'm auto forwarding the important ones to my iCloud mail. I am not disabling it as I want to reply to the mails from it that are being forwarded to my iCloud email. As my Gmail is being heavily spammed I want to stop syncing it with out disabling it. Or how can I add my gmail as alias in iCloud mail?

Comment: Are you marking them as spam, or are you setting up your own filters?

Comment: I'm setting up my own filters

Comment: Doesn't marking the emails as Spam via the Gmail web interface help?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the account from iCloud which will not disable it you just won't get the emails anymore; you can still log into it via a web browser if you like. Adding the email address as an alias would only allow you to send an email from one account but having it say it's from the other.

Comment: Nice DP! What character it is?